# unable to download image using request in python url send me html in respons?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm unable to download images using different packages
my code

```
url_h='https://i8.amplience.net/i/nlyscandinavia/086399-0001_01/i-light-rib-polo-top/'

response=requests.get(url_h,stream=True).content
with open('pic2.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
    handle.write(response)
```

2nd method

```
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response))
```

I have tried different solution but not working wget, urllib etc but not working printing response in 429

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mobin/PycharmProjects/nelly/source/test.py", line 23, in <module>
        aux_im = Image.open(requests.get(url_h, stream=True).content)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2548, in open
        fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;i8&#46;amplience&#46;net&#47;i&#47;nlyscandinavia&#47;086399&#45;0001&#95;01&#47;i&#45;light&#45;rib&#45;polo&#45;top&#47;" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;87647b5c&#46;1577361511&#46;23f0f869\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
```

Edit

Comment: Why don't you read the message sent back to you by the server? "_You don't have permission to access..._" BTW, wget works just fine.

Comment: @DYZ it's not about `Permission` at all, it's about `User-Agent`, check my answer below.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη The last line of the example clearly says that the user doe not have permission (read beyond `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`). The cause, indeed, is the same: the lack of the User-Agent

Comment: @DYZ if you taken a look about the reason of error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` it's actually due to `fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")` where `rb` is equal to `read byte` which should be `wb` [write byte] ,and the real issue is on `<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>` which is due to `User-Agent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you were getting response code [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) which is assigned to `Too Many Requests` with description of `The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time. Intended for use with rate-limiting schemes`

But in your case it can be Bypassed via `User-Agent` to be in `Headers`, you don't need to use `stream=True` as well since it's already an open stream url.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'}
r = requests.get(
    "https://i8.amplience.net/i/nlyscandinavia/086399-0001_01/i-light-rib-polo-top/", headers=headers)

with open("photo.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Still unable to download...I'm downloading multiple pictures at the same time but now its giving me `respons.ok and 200 code` but the file which download have 0 bytes size..

Comment: @mobinalhassan welcome to `Stack Overflow!` community, you have asked about one thing and i already replied according to it. Kindly please edit your question with the full details in order to be able to help you.