# Reading image from url takes too long

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-requests, python-imaging-library

Here’s the code I used:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io
import cv2
response = requests.get(df1.URL[0]).content

im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response))
```

The image is very large. Is there a way to fasten things?
EDIT:
I don't want to save image on disk. I just want to read it on the fly.

Comment: What's the URL please?

Comment: Do you only have a single image to fetch, or multiple?

Comment: @MarkSetchell df1.URL is a column of the dataframe that contains the url of the image. Every row contains one url. But I'm going to do this for all rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read image data from a URL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python)

Comment: If you have lots of images to download, the answer is different, but your question title and code both imply you only have one image! You should look at multithreading to get lots of I/O done in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to have this question clear as for now. Could you please check the timing between your code and the code below on a single image. and let us know the difference.

In case if you looking to deal with multiple images, so you need `threading` etc.. `concurrent.futures`

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url)

with open("out.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

also kindly set `stream=True` and give it a try

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io
import cv2
response = requests.get(df1.URL[0],stream=True).content

im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response))
```

Comment: Why will this read the image faster? It appears to use the same `requests.get()` as the OP.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the point here is `PIL` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495998/unable-to-download-image-using-request-in-python-url-send-me-html-in-respons/59496067#59496067

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Is there a way to not save image? I don't have much disk space on google colab. So this will be a problem going forwards

Comment: @bookfreak what's the size of `pic` is ?

Comment: @ αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη. It varies but from 3 Mo and up. And there are 5000 of them. Each url fetches one image. But I mean overall I'll fetch 5000 images.

Comment: @bookfreak check my updated answer and let me know.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη that's my initial code. It's the one that loads for a very long time. Your initial answer does the job quickly but has the problem of storage.

Comment: @bookfreak pay attention that i used `StringIO`

Comment: @ αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Sorry didn't see it. It gives TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes.

Comment: I have read the link you provided but I still fail to see why or how `response = requests.get(df1.URL[0]).content` can run at a different speed from `r = requests.get(url)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm not about `requests.get`, I just telling you that `PIL` causing a slowness while opening the image on the fly, that's why i commented for you with `the point here is PIL`. Indeed `requests.get(df1.URL[0]).content` is equal to `r = requests.get(url)` but I'm about the operation which is done after the requests. there's big difference between downloading the image, and streaming the image on the fly.

Comment: So, if the difference is not in `requests.get()`, are you saying that `img = Image.open(StringIO(response.content))` is significantly faster than `im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response))` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure not !!! I'm saying that downloading the image and then opening it is pretty faster than streaming it while on the fly !! the point of `StringIO` is for checking different thing from `bytes` to `string`

Comment: I still don't understand. OP wrote `requests.get()` followed by `Image.open()` and you suggested `requests.get()` followed by `Image.open()` and you say neither of your 2 lines are faster than the OP's two lines, so how can your code be faster?

Comment: well you are missing a part, again i repeat.  `f.write(r.content)` is different than `im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response))` and regarding `Image.open()` after i suggested `stream=True`

Comment: `f.write()` is about saving an image. OP was asking about *"Reading from a URL"*, and specifically says in the comments that he wants to avoid saving it!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did not look to the title, as i were working on the content. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59561093/revisions as `EDIT: I don't want to save image on disk. I just want to read it on the fly.` was an EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη for your help.
I made a comparison between duration of loading for different methods.
Here's a link to see results [comparison](https://github.com/imazerty/All-In-One-Underwater-Image-Enhancement-using-Domain-Adversarial-Learning/blob/master/load_im_url.ipynb)

Comment: kindly be informed that `answer` section is not for replying me back. please edit your question and include the comparison details. and you can delete this answer by clicking on `delete` under the answer.